# Multibyte character issue with .match?

Tags: ruby, regex, multibyte

The following code is something I am beginning to test for use within a "Texas Hold Em" style game I am working on.

My question is why, when running the following code, does the puts involving a "♥" return a "\u" in it's place. I feel certain it is this multibyte character that is causing the issue becuse on the second puts , I replaced the ♦ with a d in the array of strings and it returned what i was expecting. See Below:

**My Code:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

table_cards = ["|2♥|", "|8♥|", "|6d|", "|6♣|", "|Q♠|"]

# Array of cards

player_1_face_1 = "8"
player_1_suit_1 = "♦"

# Player 1's face and suit of first card he has

player_1_face_2 = "6"
player_1_suit_2 = "♥"

# Player 1's face and suit of second card he has

test_str_1 = /(\D8\D{2})/.match(table_cards.to_s)

# EX: Searching for match between face values on (player 1's |8♦|) and the |8♥| on the table

test_str_2 = /(\D6\D{2})/.match(table_cards.to_s)

# EX: Searching for match between face values on (player 1's |6♥|) and the |6d| on the table

puts "#{test_str_1}"
puts "#{test_str_2}"
```

**Puts to Screen:**

```
|8\u

|6d|
```

-- My goal would be to get the first puts to return: |8♥|

I am not so much looking for a solution to this (there may not even be one) but more so a "as simple as possible" explanation of what is causing this issue and why.  Thanks ahead of time for any information on what is happening here and how I can tackle the goal.

Comment: Printing Unicode characters to the screen involves more than your Ruby script having the proper encoding. It also requires your console to be using the same codeset. If that is set to something else then these sort of things can happen. Windows typically uses Win1252 or ISO-8859-1 and the character definitions don't match causing weird output.

Comment: Is this really related to `match`? Have you tried `puts "♥"`?

Comment: @ Anthony

I am using Windows 8.1  All my coding has been happening in Aptana Studio

Comment: @ the Tin Man
I am assuming joelparkerhenderson's answer is the workaround for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "\u" you're seeing is the Unicode string indicator.

For example, Unicode character 'HEAVY BLACK HEART' (U+2764) can be printed as "\u2764".

A friendly Unicode character listing site is http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/

Are you able to launch interactive Ruby in your shell and print a heart like this?

```
irb
irb> puts "\u2764"
❤
```

When I run your code in my Ruby, I get the answer you expect:

```
test_str_1 = /(\D8\D{2})/.match(table_cards.to_s)
=> #<MatchData "|8♥|" 1:"|8♥|">
```

What happens if you try a regex that is more specific to your cards?

```
 test_str_1 = /(\|8[♥♦♣♠]\|)/.match(table_cards.to_s)
```

In your example output, you're not seeing the Unicode heart symbol as you want. Instead, your output is printing the "\u" which is the Unicode starter, but then not printing the rest of the expected string which is "2764".

- See the comment by the Tin Man that describes encoding for your console. If he's correct, then I expect the more-specific regex will succeed, but still print the wrong output.
- See the comment by David Knipe that says it looks like it gets truncated because the regex only matches 4 characters. If he's correct, then I expect the more-specific regex will succeed and also print the right output.

(The rest of this answer is typical for Unix; if you're on Windows, ignore the rest here...)

To show your system language settings, try this in your shell:

```
echo $LC_ALL
echo $LC_CTYPE
```

If they are not "UTF-8" or something like that, try this in your shell:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then re-run your code -- be sure to use the same shell.

If this works, and you want to make this permanent, one way is to add these here:

```
# /etc/environment
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then source that file from your .bashrc or .zshrc or whatever shell startup file you use.

Comment: This worked. Is there a website with a listing of all these unicodes? like "\u2764" = ♥   ? If so that's be really helpful for me.

Comment: I will openly admit most of what you added after your initial post was completely over my head. Sounds something akin to working in Linux which I am very limited on. and $ cmd written in windows' shell yields an error as not recognized. But your first bit helps me a ton! Thanks. And Thanks for the site

Comment: 'Your output seems to print the "\u" then swallow the rest of the string. Possibly this is because your system's locale is not set to use Unicode.'. No, if it's using `\u` it will be `|\u2666|` or something similar, which is all ASCII. It looks to me like it gets truncated because the regex only matches 4 characters. (But why it was `|\u2666|` in the first place I have not idea.)

Comment: @ David Knipe

The idea behind this testing was to "look for a pair", So I was aiming to find a way to have it check for a match of 4 characters |#"suit"|, the only of which I cared for it to actually look for was the 8 in one case and the 6 in the other case. I ould have just used /8/ and /6/ I suppose but there were other reasons that i had been looking to capture the whole "card" string. if that makes sense

Comment: @Arc_X Yes, I totally understand why you used that regex. It's not that you've used the wrong regex, it's that for some reason the character is being escaped before it goes into the regex, so it's regexing the wrong string. I was disagreeing with joelparkerhenderson, not you.